# How would I report a bug in the paste.ubuntu.com service?

Tags: bug-reporting

I assume that http://paste.ubuntu.com/ is an official service from Ubuntu, other "Ubuntu" sites have a link to report problems with them (for example [apps.ubuntu.com](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/) - which links to launchpad and has is [own page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-webcatalog))

But with Ubuntu Pastebin I can't find any way to report a problem, or a specfic Launchpad page which deals with site. Is there one for it, and if not how should I report a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't have its own Launchpad site but you can post bugs for all official ubuntu web content [on the ubuntu-website-content Launchpad section](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-website-content). See for example [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-website-content/+bug/784485).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the launchpad site to report bugs related to paste.ubuntu.com. https://bugs.launchpad.net/canonical-pastebin